# Hyperlinks from Envato on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I recently submitted an Envato theme to Wordpress for a website.
Now when I click on the hyperlinks, I am always directed to the homepage.
I want each tab on the navbar to have a distinct content. How can I add different content and hyperlink to each tab on the navbar?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way:

1. Create all the necessary pages of the website and put contents on each page
2. Proceed on menu arrangement

To answer your question, maybe you missed checking and editing the Dashboard > Appearance > Menu?